# How would I separate one value of an array (for the entire array) into alphabetic and numeric characters, and then into separate arrays? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I've been struggling to find an answer to my specific problem here. I understand that I can use regex to separate array values, but they both don't seem to work and I can't figure out how to get the two values separately. Thanks!

Here's my code without any separation of `arr`:

```
package boomaa;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("A.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        for (int i = 1;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My input is formatted like this:

```
3
1 CS
2 CS
1 SS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers and characters are separated by a space, simply iterate over the array and use the String method `split` to split at the space.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("A.txt"));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   lines.add(sc.nextLine());
}

String[] numbers = new String[lines.size()];
String[] characters = new String[lines.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String[] components = lines.get(i).split(" ");
    numbers[i] = components[0];
    characters[i] = components[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I compile this it gives me an error saying that `split()` can't have `' '` as an argument.

Comment: @Boomaa Sorry. Used to C# allowing chars as an argument for split. Try double quotes `" "`.